# JS Function not working for Multiple Input Text Fields In Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, function

I am attempting to check the field to determine whether or not it is a number (no non-numeric characters except .). If the field's value is a number, convert it to a two-decimal format. Currently the code is working in FireFox and Chrome, but I am having trouble with Internet Explorer (multiple versions, specifically tested on IE8 and IE9). I have been messing around with it for a few hours and haven't been able to look up a solution to the problem. In Internet Explorer, only the first field works correctly. The other fields do not work correctly and Internet Explorer does not trigger an error.

This is the relevant code in the html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">

 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="amount.js"></script>
 </head>

 <body>
  <input type="text" id="amount1" onChange="changeAmount(this.id);"/>
  <input type="text" id="amount2" onChange="changeAmount(this.id);"/>
  <input type="text" id="amount3" onChange="changeAmount(this.id);"/>
  <input type="text" id="amount4" onChange="changeAmount(this.id);"/>
  <input type="text" id="amount5" onChange="changeAmount(this.id);"/>
 </body>
</html>
```

This is the relevant code from amount.js:

```
function changeAmount(input)
{
   var pattern = /([^0-9\.])+/;
   var ctl = document.getElementById(input);
   var myvalue = ctl.value;

   if(myvalue != "" && !pattern.test(myvalue))
   {
     myvalue = parseFloat(myvalue);
     myvalue = myvalue.toFixed(2);
     if(!pattern.test(myvalue))
     {
        ctl.value = myvalue;
     }else
     {
        ctl.value = '';
     }
   }
}
```

I am going to browse some more threads on here to see if I can't find the solution.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: copy-paste error? `if(myvalue != "" && !pattern.text(myvalue))`

Comment: @jbabey - good eye, should probably be `test` (or match) !

Comment: Instead of passing `this.id` to the function, just pass `this`. Then, you can get the element with `input`, its value with `input.value`, and anything else with `input.whatever`. You can eliminate the whole `document.getElementById` part. This wouldn't fix anything, it's just a suggestion

Comment: Oops on the text instead of test part, but it's correct in the actual file.

Thanks for the tip Ian, that seems handy. Wasn't aware I could do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="amount1" onChange="changeAmount(this);"/>
<input type="text" id="amount2" onChange="changeAmount(this);"/>
<input type="text" id="amount3" onChange="changeAmount(this);"/>
<input type="text" id="amount4" onChange="changeAmount(this);"/>
<input type="text" id="amount5" onChange="changeAmount(this);"/>
```

Try using this Javascript:

```
function changeAmount(input) {
    var myvalue = input.value;
    myvalue = parseFloat(myvalue);
    if (!isNaN(myvalue)) {
        input.value = myvalue.toFixed(2);
    } else {
        input.value = "";
    }
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/7rDeg/4/

It uses my recommended change of passing `this` instead of `this.value` to the function.

Also, there's no need for regular expressions. Just attempt to parse the value with `parseFloat`. If it's a success, then fix the number with 2 decimals and re-set the input's value. Otherwise, clear the textbox.

**UPDATE:**

While that should all work fine, I'd recommend against using inline event handlers. So for example, it's ideal to use this HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="amount1" />
<input type="text" id="amount2" />
<input type="text" id="amount3" />
<input type="text" id="amount4" />
<input type="text" id="amount5" />
```

with this Javascript:

```
function changeAmount() {
    var myvalue = this.value;
    myvalue = parseFloat(myvalue);
    if (!isNaN(myvalue)) {
        this.value = myvalue.toFixed(2);
    } else {
        this.value = "";
    }
}

function addEvent(element, eventName, callback) {
    if (element.addEventListener) {
        element.addEventListener(eventName, callback, false);
    } else if (element.attachEvent) {
        element.attachEvent("on" + eventName, callback);
    } else {
        element["on" + eventName] = callback;
    }
}

window.onload = function () {
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        if (inputs[i].type === "text") {
            addEvent(inputs[i], "change", changeAmount);
        }
    }
};
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/7rDeg/6/

*Note:* With `parseFloat`, it will strip any trailing non-numeric characters. For example, the input "234.35234a" will be parsed as "234.35234" (therefore passing the `!isNaN(myvalue)` condition) and fixed as "234.35". If you don't want this to happen use:

```
myvalue = +myvalue;
```

instead of the `parseFloat` line.

Comment: This definitely makes the code cleaner, thank you. This code doesn't seem to work in IE 8 or 9 for fields 2-5 still for some reason. Not sure what's going on there. I was hoping internet explorer just had some kind of trouble with getElementById.

Comment: @user2292219 There's nothing that shouldn't work for IE in either of our code. You do know that IE has weird caching, right? Your code is in an external file, and that will be cached immediately. Meaning, if you make a change and re-visit your page, your changes most likely won't be applied. You need to clear the cache. Are you sure that's not the problem? My jsFiddle works, doesn't it?

Comment: I may be doing something incorrectly, but jsFiddle does not appear to be working for my IE8 browser. It does load properly in Chrome.

Comment: Okay, your most recently updated solution does work in IE. I took a closer look at my code and realized I had the first field using onBlur and 2-5 were using onChange. Is onChange not supported by Internet Explorer? Thank you for helping me find the solution by the way!

Comment: @user2292219 I don't think jsFiddles work for older than IE version 9...not sure though. And IE shouldn't have any trouble with the `onchange` event...it's supported by all browsers. So I'm not sure what the problem would be with that. And no problem helping out, glad we could fix it :)